# Is it possible to open & read a text file based on user input?

Tags: java

I would like to open a text file based on the user input.
For example, if the user typed "John", i would then like to open up John.txt and read it. Is it possible to do it?
If it's possible, is it possible to do with the library **`java.io.File`**?

To make it simpler,

```
File file = new File("Peter.txt");
```

The file name to be opened will based on what the user has keyed in so if the user keyed in Mary, the File that will be opened will be **`"Mary.txt" instead of "Peter.txt"`**.

Comment: Yes it is possible. The file name is just a `String` so you can construct it based on the user input.

Comment: Short Answer: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Does that mean I will need to add a " .txt " at the end of the user's input and i will save it to a new string. After which I will pass it as argument?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
String name = user_input.next( );              // asks you for input
    if(name!=null && !name.equals("")){        // in case you don't give input
          File file = new File(name + ".txt" );
    }
```

[getting user input](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html)

[learn about files](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm)

Note, that you should surround it with a `try-cach`, in case the file with that name doesn't exist.